# Critical references needed in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Helo

What are the critical references needed in an access 2016 database.

What would happen if l selected all the references

Thank you
Sichilaba

Answer (score 0):

> What are the critical references needed in an access 2016 database.

Those needed for your code to compile.

> What would happen if l selected all the references

If not referencing more than one version for each, nothing.

Why don't you just try it?